# Shutdown scripts not being run on GCE instances with GPU and NVIDIA driver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to run shutdown scripts on GCE instances with an NVIDIA K80 GPU (guest accelerator). These instances (n1-standard-1) are running a custom image of Ubuntu 16.04 (which has the NVIDIA driver installed, as in this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#install-driver-manual) in the us-east-1d zone.

The issue is that the shutdown script isn't being run when the instance has the NVIDIA driver installed, but consistently executes if the driver isn't installed (even when the GPU is attached). This is happening regardless of whether the instance is preemptible or not.

Running the shutdown script on the standard Ubuntu 16.04 OS image works, but as soon as the driver is installed, and the instance restarted, shutting it down doesn't trigger the script anymore. Interestingly, /var/log/syslog contains no message of the shutdown script. I would either expect an error or the message that no shutdown script was found, but none of these appear.

Any help or information about whether this is reproducible or just some mistake on my part would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it in my project with an NVIDIA K80 GPU and in both cases with and without I have been able to run the shutdown script. Did you actually made a test removing the GPU or are you using 2 different instances?

You can try to add the  script in the custom metadata of the instances in order to check that it is not an issue with the way you connect to the bucket/permissions or of the script itself (but honestly I do no know how these can be the causes of the issues).

Therefore go to the edit page of any instances and add custom metadata and retry and let me know the result.

```
key = shutdown-script
value = echo hello >> marco.py
```

Remember that from the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) shutdown script output is written to the following log files:

- CentOS and RHEL: /var/log/messages
- Debian: /var/log/daemon.log
- Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, and 16.10: /var/log/syslog
- SLES 11 and 12: /var/log/messages

### UPDATE

I created the public issue that you can "star" in order to follow its updates.
You need to login with any gmail account in order to check it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72981924

Comment: Thank you for the response! After reading your answer, I also ran the shutdown script on a base Ubuntu 16.04 image and it worked. It seems like the installation of the NVIDIA driver (Following these steps for Ubuntu 16.04: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#install-driver-manual) leads to the shutdown script not being run. After restarting the instance where the driver was just installed and shutting it down again, the shutdown script doesn't run anymore. Execution of the shutdown script doesn't show up in /var/log/syslog at all (not even a "shutdown script missing" message).

Comment: Hello, I performed some tests, the shutdown script is working in case of Ubuntu 17.10 after you install the drivers, but for some reason it is not for 16.04. I will report this unexpected behaviour and I will create an open issue where you will be able to star it and follow its resolution. I will update my answer with all the information needed. Please consider to accept and upvote the answer if it has been useful! (Disclaimer: I work for the Google Cloud Platform Support)

Comment: I created the public issue as promised.